# Alignment in function definitions

Tags: math-mode, align, arrays

I have the following code for the definition of a function

```
\begin{align*}
\varphi_{\sigma}\colon  &E \longrightarrow E \\
&(x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n}) \longmapsto        
(x_{\sigma(1)},x_{\sigma(2)},...,x_{\sigma(n)}).
\end{align*}
```

I find this rather ugly and I would like the arrows also to be aligned. I couldn't manage to do it within the `align` environment. I can do it with the `array` environment, but this doesn't render well either, because the space between the math and the body text changes.

Comment: You can use `alignat*` instead, but I would not be obsessed trying to align these at all; a single line or a `gather*` or writing `\varphi(x_1,...)=...` may be better.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post always a compilable document, not just fragments

Comment: Thanks ! I suppose you mean add packages before my code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same initial solution as @Gonzalo Medina, but added a solution using the `\medmath` command from the `nccmath` package, that reduces the size of the $n$-tuples by about 30 %:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[overload]{empheq}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  φ_{σ}\colon E & ―――→ E \\
  (x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n}) & \longmapsto
  (x_{σ(1)},x_{σ(2)},...,x_{σ(n)}).
\end{align*}
\vskip 1cm

\verb+With \medmath+:
\begin{align*}
  φ_{σ}\colon E & ―――→ E \\[-0.5ex]
  \medmath{(x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n})} & \longmapsto
  \medmath{(x_{σ(1)},x_{σ(2)},...,x_{σ(n)}).}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks ! I finally adopted an array nested inside an equation environement, but the medmath function may be useful !

Answer (score 1):

You can align at the arrows, but this might look odd since the n-tuple is too wide; another approach is to give up on alignment, be a little wordy and separate the components:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\varphi_{\sigma}\colon  E &\longrightarrow E \\
(x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n}) &\longmapsto        
(x_{\sigma(1)},x_{\sigma(2)},...,x_{\sigma(n)}).
\end{align*}

We have the mapping $\varphi_{\sigma}\colon  E \longrightarrow E$
such that 
\[
(x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n}) \longmapsto        
(x_{\sigma(1)},x_{\sigma(2)},...,x_{\sigma(n)}).
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried your first proposition but I agree with you that it isn't very satisfactory: the name of the endomorphism is hardly visible. I don't mind at all being wordy and perhaps I'll adopt your second formulation but it doesn't satisfy me entirely...

Comment: @Sergio You could use `(x_i) \mapsto (x_{\sigma(i)})`. But that might not be of the like of some people, in any case, `x_i \mapsto x_{\sigma(i)}` is something that you could always use.